# Would adding ice to a ultrasonic humidifier help cooling in summer?

Tags: cooling, humidifier

During summer it's way too hot for me to sleep well.

I currently use a fan, but it's so hot that it's not enough.

I had the idea of having a sonic humidifier in front of the fan as the fan would move the water particles into my body and then when the water evaporates it would cool me down.

Would adding ice to the humidifier water create a cooler mist?

Comment: the last thing you want is more humidity...

Comment: your question makes absolutely no sense  ..... you have an ultrasonic humidifier and you have ice .... why don't you simply try your idea and find out for yourself instead of asking a question about it

Comment: Why are you humidifying in summer?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you live in the desert and use a swamp (evaporative) cooler.  Most areas use an air conditioner to remove humidity, not add it.  Adding more moisture will only make it feel hotter and muggier.

Comment: What is a SWAMP EVAPORATIVE COOLER ?

Comment: A swamp cooler blows air across water in order to cause the water to evaporate. You could make one with a bowl of water, a fan, and a towel dipped in the water, and held up by some sort of framework.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Eric's answer, a swamp cooler uses the evaporation of water to cool the environment. It works because water turning from a liquid to a gas takes work, which is taken from the air as heat.

However, swamp coolers use water, not ice. The energy required to turn 1kg of ice to water is 334kJ, while the energy required to turn 1kg of water to vapor is 2256kJ, almost 7 times as much. Considering the logistical issues around getting ice, compared to getting water, the extra cooling isn't really worth it.

And, of course, the extra humidity this adds is usually not great, except in specific environments.

Now, how to do this properly:

- Get a cross-breeze going. Assuming you sleep at night, it'll usually be cooler outside. Open two windows (preferably on opposite sides of the home), open doors between them, and get a fan to encourage air movement.
- Examine your bed. Some bed types are better than others for comfort during hot weather. Memory foam, for example, tends to retain a lot more heat than you want. On the opposite end, hammocks basically do not retain heat at all. (Though they do require getting used to.) There are other technologies between those two extremes. (Don't forget to examine your sheets as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you live, it's actually not a bad idea. Basically the entire western part of North America is a rather dry climate, so evaporative coolers are actually a better idea than fans by themselves. I add ice to my humidifier and put a strong fan behind it and it cools my room down incredibly well. Just make sure that you have at least 3/4 tank of water first before you add the ice as you can damage the the piece that atomizers the water.